# Creating a Heatmap Matrix using two categorical values at axis and average of third column as value

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataset with 3 column looks like below example (actual dataset has 30K rows) :

| age group | heightGroup | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4-5 | 60-70 | 50 |
| 5-6 | 70-80 | 52 |
| 4-5 | 70-80 | 50 |
| 5-6 | 70-80 | 57 |
| 6-7 | 60-70 | 54 |
| 4-5 | 50-60 | 50 |
| 5-6 | 70-80 | 43 |

I'm trying to create a heat map Y axis is age group and X axis is height group as categorical value
value at each block of heat map will be average weights for that block of Heatmap how can visualize this matrix at python ?
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `pivot_table` aggregating the mean of the weights. If needed, the heights and ages could be made categorical to fix a certain order.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''"age group" heightGroup weight
4-5 60-70   50
5-6 70-80   52
4-5 70-80   50
5-6 70-80   57
6-7 60-70   54
4-5 50-60   50
5-6 70-80   43'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
df_pivoted = df.pivot_table("weight", "age group", "heightGroup", aggfunc='mean')
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df_pivoted, annot=True, fmt='.1f')
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn heatmap on pivot_table]

PS: To mask out all cells with a count of 1 (or 0):

```py
df_pivoted_count = df.pivot_table("weight", "age group", "heightGroup", aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df_pivoted, mask=df_pivoted_count <= 1, annot=True, fmt='.1f')
```

To show the heatmap with the counts for coloring: the counts dataframe (without `.fillna()`) can be used for `data=` and the means for `annot=`. The code below also changes the colorbar ticks to prevent that in this example, non-integer ticks would be shown.

```py
df_pivoted = df.pivot_table("weight", "age group", "heightGroup", aggfunc='mean')
df_pivoted_count = df.pivot_table("weight", "age group", "heightGroup", aggfunc='count')
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df_pivoted_count, annot=df_pivoted, fmt='.1f', cmap='flare',
                 linecolor='skyblue', lw='2', clip_on=False, square=True,
                 cbar_kws={'ticks': range(1, int(df_pivoted_count.max().max()+1))})
```

[image: using count for the coloring]

Comment: Thank you for answering above I have a followup question if we want to limit the heatmap to only values with count of more than 1 how we add condition to this ?

Comment: This is a great solution to mask the answers at the pivot result and works at many cased  but here I wanted to re-calculate the heatmap colors with new scale and not only mask them .

Comment: When you use a mask, the colors are automatically calculated only taking the unmasked values into account.

Comment: That is great answer, big help today

Comment: I've deleted the duplicate post and here was the difference . as you can see 50.7 shows as hottest if we want to show the 54.0 as the hottest then 50.7 and 50 as the coldest how you do that ,the purpose is to keep the color as the mean but the remove any values repeated less than two .

Comment: Well, that is with `df_pivoted_count = df.pivot_table("weight", "age group", "heightGroup", aggfunc='count').fillna(0)` and `ax = sns.heatmap(data=df_pivoted, mask=df_pivoted_count <= 1, annot=True, fmt='.1f')`.  So, `mean` for coloring and for annotation. And `count < 2` for filtering. But for some reason, you wanted still something else. I really don't understand.

Comment: No that is all I was looking for ,you are amazing and how can I appreciate you !!!